# Cakephp : Error handling issue (error not inserting in error_log table)

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-3.0

In our app, we are handing all error and inserting in tbl_error_log table. But due to some reason it has stopped work and now no error is inserting in error_log table except initialize function error. If error in initialize function then it is working. We are using below code for inserting error.

File path : `Vendor/Cakephp/Cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorhandler.php`

```
protected function _logError($level, $data) {
    $ErrorLogTable = TableRegistry::get('tbl_error_log');
    $errorlog      = $ErrorLogTable->newEntity();

    $errorlog->in_user_id       = $User['member_id'];
    $errorlog->st_email_address = $User['email'];
    $errorlog->in_error_no      = $data['code'];
    $errorlog->st_error_type    = $data['error'];
    $errorlog->st_error_string  = $data['description'];
    $errorlog->st_error_file    = $data['file'];
    $errorlog->in_error_line_no = $data['line'];
    $errorlog->dt_error_time    = new \DateTime('now');
    $errorlog->st_from_ip       = $this->getClientIp();

    $ErrorLogTable->save($errorlog);
}
```

Comment: Where is `$User` coming from ?

Comment: Coming from session but I have removed session code while posting question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about your problem with errors only logged from certain code parts, but generally that's not how to do custo logging. *Never modify vendor files* (unless for testing purposes of course), they will eventually be overwritten when updating the dependencies.

If you want to implement custom logging functionality, then create a custom logger as shown in the docs:

```
// src/Log/Engine/DatabaseLog.php

namespace App\Log\Engine;
use Cake\Log\Engine\BaseLog;

class DatabaseLog extends BaseLog
{
    public function __construct($options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        // ...
    }

    public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
    {
        // Write to the database.
    }
}
```

See **[Cookbook > Logging > Creating Log Adapters](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-log-adapters)**

You can use it as the default logger by changing the configuration in your `config/app.php` file accordingly:

```
'Log' => [
    'debug' => [
        'className' => 'Database',
        'scopes' => false,
        'levels' => ['notice', 'info', 'debug'],
    ],
    'error' => [
        'className' => 'Database',
        'scopes' => false,
        'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Comment: I go through your code but still it is working with only initialize function.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I don't know what exactly you mean by that, you have to describe your problem _in detail_. My answer is solely to inform you about how to do custom logging the right way.

Comment: For example : I have DashboardController and it has 2-3 functions like index, getuserData and other one is initialize at top where we can initilize or load our component and modal. So error are handling in only initialize function but not in any other functios. let me know if need more clarification.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I see, but I can't really help you with that, as there's no obvious reproducible problem here. You'll have to do some further debugging, start with checking whether the logger is being invoked at all in those cases, and if it is, check what data it receies, and whether the `Table::save()` call actually succeeds.